# Difference between FUSE and VFS in linux?

Tags: filesystem, gvfs, fuse

What is the difference between VFS [Virtual File System] and FUSE [File System in User Space] in linux. I think, most of the popular OS today support VFS feature. I recently had a chance to go through FUSE wiki on source forge and I assumed FUSE would provide as API for implementing wrapper functions for file operations while the actual file operations are done by low-level file system that resides in the Kernel. Isn't this what VFS does?

1. What is the boundary between VFS and FUSE?
2. Can I imagine this as - FUSE on top of VFS on top of actual kernel file system?

Any pointers in this direction would be really helpful. Thanks for looking at this, and for your time.

Comment: See [What is a Virtual filesystem or a filesystem in userspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910229/what-is-a-virtual-file-system-or-a-file-system-in-userspace) on StackOverflow